# How can I replace newlines/line breaks with spaces in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a var that contains a big list of words (millions) in this format:

```
var words =  "
car
house
home
computer
go 
went
";
```

I want to make a function that will replace the newline between each word with space.

So the results would something look like this:

```
car house home computer go went
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can use the `.replace()` function:

```
words = words.replace(/\n/g, " ");
```

Note that you need the `g` flag on the regular expression to get replace to replace all the newlines with a space rather than just the first one.

Also, note that you have to assign the result of the `.replace()` to a variable because it returns a new string.  It does not modify the existing string.   Strings in Javascript are immutable (they aren't directly modified) so any modification operation on a string like `.slice()`, `.concat()`, `.replace()`, etc... returns a new string.

```js
let words = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne";
console.log("Before:");
console.log(words);
words = words.replace(/\n/g, " ");

console.log("After:");
console.log(words);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Downvoters that offer no explanation don't help us improve our answers (thus benefiting the whole community).

Answer (score 92):

In case there are *multiple* line breaks (newline symbols) and if there can be both `\r` or `\n`, and you need to *replace all subsequent linebreaks* with *one space*, use

```
var new_words = words.replace(/[\r\n]+/g," ");
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM9zY5/1)

To match **all Unicode line break characters** and replace/remove them, add `\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029` to the above regex:

```
/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g
```

The `/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g` means:

- `[` - start of a positive character class matching any single char defined inside it:

  - `\r` - (`\x0D`) - `\n]` - a carriage return (CR)
  - `\n` - (`\x0A`) - a line feed character (LF)
  - `\x0B` - a line tabulation (LT)
  - `\x0C` - form feed (FF)
  - `\u0085` - next line (NEL)
  - `\u2028` - line separator (LS)
  - `\u2029` - paragraph separator (PS)
- `]` - end of the character class
- `+` - a quantifier that makes the regex engine match the previous atom (the character class here) one or more times (consecutive linebreaks are matched)
- `/g` - find and replace all occurrences in the provided string.

```js
var words = "car\r\n\r\nhouse\nhome\rcomputer\ngo\n\nwent";
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>OLD:\n" + words + "</pre>";
var new_words = words.replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g," ");
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>NEW:\n" + new_words + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 7):

**Code :** (FIXED)

```
var new_words = words.replace(/\n/g," ");
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  It doesn't seem to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zn4WE/1/

Comment: @jfriend00 @Madmartigan TRUE. Sometimes, the obvious is overlooked... (without the `/g` flag, only the first occurence is replaced)

Answer (score 2):

Some simple solution would look like

```
words.replace(/(\n)/g," ");
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? It doesn't seem to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zn4WE/1

Comment: Why the parens in `/(\n)/`?  They aren't needed.

Comment: they are indeed redundant but i prefer to put them to be clearer

Answer (score 2):

No need for global regex, use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`

```
myString.replaceAll('\n', ' ')
```

Comment: Upvoted, can u explain why other solution have large space but yours solution have exactly what is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const words = `He had 
concluded that pigs 
must be able 
to fly in Hog Heaven.
`
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>without-Trim-And-Remove:\n" + words + "</pre>";

trimAndRemoveSymbols=(text)=>{
        return text.replace(/[\n]+/g, '').trim();
    }
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>Trim-And-Remove:\n" + trimAndRemoveSymbols(words) + "</pre>";
```