# Why is my alert box not showing proper text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I am displaying an alert box after clicking on a button but the string text is going down.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('input[name="addtocart"]').each(function()
{
    jQuery(this).on("click", function(event)
    {
        qty = jQuery(this).parent().find('input[name="qty"]').val();
        var qty1 = parseFloat(qty);
        qth = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.qtyonhand').text();
        var qth1 = parseFloat(qth);
        itemName = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.cell-desc          
        span').text();
        if(qty1 > qth1){
            alert("For the following item, the ordered quantity exceeds the  
            current available quantity.Please adjust the quantity and  
            retry.\n"+itemName+"-"+"Available Qty:"+qth1);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the image:

[image: Alert Message]

In the above image, availability text is displaying on the next line.
How can I display the string in a single line? Please help.

Comment: Use `...+itemName.trim()+"-"+"Available...`

Comment: Thanks its working fine

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to replace the newlines with spaces.
Add this code before the `if` statement:

```
itemName = itemName.replace(/\n/g, " ");
```

Regex comes from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849754/how-can-i-replace-newlines-line-breaks-with-spaces-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(qty1 > qth1){
   alert("For the following item, the ordered quantity exceeds the  
   current available quantity.Please adjust the quantity and       
   retry."+itemName+"-"+"Available Qty:"+qth1);
}
```

Please remove the \n from the alert content