# How to remove empty lines at the end of line

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm creating a webpage which checks whether the data given by the user matches the data in the webpage's script.

My code:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("p");
function checking() {
   if (b.innerHTML == a.value){
        alert("All is perfect");
   } else {
        alert("Please check again");
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Terms and Conditions Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="a" autocomplete="off" />
<button onclick="checking()">Check</button>
<div id="p" style="display:none;">
a
b
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I want to replace the empty spaces at the end of the lines with a space inside the `<div>`. So, if the code is

```
<div id="p" style="display:none;">
a
b
</div>
```

it should match:

```
<div id="p" style="display:none;"> a b </div>
```

Comment: You want do add spaces around or remove them?

Comment: I want to replace them with a space.

Comment: Add more details, provide screenshot of what appears and you want to change it?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this? O:-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849754/how-can-i-replace-newlines-line-breaks-with-spaces-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all tab , enter and using regex `/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm`

See below snippet :

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("p");
function checking() {
   var val = b.innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm, "");
   console.log(a.value,val);
   if (val == a.value){
        alert("All is perfect");
   } else {
        alert("Please check again");
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Terms and Conditions Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="a" autocomplete="off" />
<button onclick="checking()">Check</button>
<div id="p" style="display:none;">
a 
b
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user9953286 is that what you mean ?