# how to remove unicode new line from javascript string

Tags: javascript

I was replacing new line with the following javascript code:

```
str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
```

However, came across some Unicode new line Unicode Character 'NEXT LINE (NEL)' (U+0085).

How to remove new lines from a string safely i.e. all these weird new lines will be removed as well?

Is it an established API for javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace newlines/line breaks with spaces in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849754/how-can-i-replace-newlines-line-breaks-with-spaces-in-javascript) The second answer there has a regex for Unicode line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

### Unicode in regular expressions with `\u`

You can reference unicode characters by prepending \u to the unicode sequence. So `U+0085` -> `\u0085`

#### Example:

```
const str = 'Need space here ->\u0085<-';
str = str.replace(/\u0085/g, ' ');
console.log(str)
// Output: Need space here -> <-
```

Here a nice read by flavio if you want to further explore dealing with Unicode chars: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/

Hope this helps