# easy way to remove all enter marks

Tags: bookmarklet

The following code that I got from this page is working as expected.

[How can I replace newlines/line breaks with spaces in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849754/how-can-i-replace-newlines-line-breaks-with-spaces-in-javascript)

```
var words = "car\r\n\r\nhouse\nhome\rcomputer\ngo\n\nwent";
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>OLD:\n" + words + "</pre>";
var new_words = words.replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g," ");
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>NEW:\n" + new_words + "</pre>";
```

But in my case, the words variable is nothing but the text in the form and I am looking for a way to convert this script into a bookmarklet. How is the bookmarklet code different from regular one?

Comment: Can you share an example of the form and what "text in the form" means in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line just initiate the value in textarea for obviousness.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').value =
  'car\r\n\r\nhouse\nhome\rcomputer\ngo\n\nwent';

function replace() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

  textarea.value = textarea.value
    .replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g, ' ');
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

<button onclick="replace();">Replace</button>
```

Bookmarklet

```js
javascript: {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

  void (textarea.value = textarea.value
    .replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g, ' '));
}
```

Bookmarklet to drag to bookmarks:

```html
<a href="javascript: {const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'); void (textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+/g, ' '));}">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: But this does not seem to work in "page body" section of wiki page. https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Page:Private_Lotteries_Act_2011.pdf/5&action=edit

Comment: @shantanuo There are some textareas there, so you need to use more specific selector to get the "page body" one: `const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea#wpTextbox1');`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `words` declaration with

```
var words = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
```

to pick up the the text content of the first textarea element on the page. [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)s have a `value` property to access their text content.